# How can I load a 'future' forms controls before I use them? Explained in detail:

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I am performing a migration on a vb6 program, to vb.net. The basic knowledge you need to understand this question is that there are two forms that need to talk to each other, frmInput1 and frmInput2.  I have the following code (behind frmInput1) that checks if a textbox on frmInput2 has a certain value, seemingly before it has loaded:

```
If frminput2.lblInputMac.Text <> "(no filename)" Then
        Dim calc As CalculationCaster = New CalculationCaster
        Call calc.FillMac()
        cmdNext.Enabled = False

        frminput2.FraInner.Enabled = True
```

I get the following error on the If line when i run it:

```
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

Which i assume means that the object in frmInput2 has not been loaded yet. How can i load frmInput2 before i show it?

Thanks

Nick

Answer (score 1):

`frminput2` is probably the implicit global instance of the *type* frminput2.

If you define a form type in VB6 called `MyForm`, the platform automatically creates an implicit global variable of the same name `MyForm`. Whenever you refer to this variable in code, it automatically loads an instance of the form for you.

It's rather as if you had this code.

```
Public Function MyForm() As MyForm
  Static f As MyForm
  If f Is Nothing Then
    f = New MyForm
  End If
  Return f
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dim frm1 as new frmInput1 
dim frm2 as new frmInput2
```

At this point, you should be able to communicate between forms without them being displayed.  You should not reference forms without explicitly instantiating them.

Comment: I tried this, and then got this error: Could not load file or assembly 'MSComDlg, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  I've restarted VS2010 but the error still stands. any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of the form.

```
Dim f As New frmInput2
```

Then you can use any properties, methods, or controls on the form.

```
If f.lblInputMac.Text  <> "(no filename)" Then
    ...
End If
```

Comment: I tried this, and then got this error: Could not load file or assembly 'MSComDlg, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  I've restarted VS2010 but the error still stands. any idea? Thanks

Comment: That looks to me as if there is a control in use on `frmInput2` that is not referenced in your Assembly. Can you load `frmInput2` in your designer? You should go through your project and (where possible) replace COM components with their .NET equivalents or make sure you've added a reference to the COM object(s) your form(s) require.

Comment: There is a CommonDialog (VB6 throwback) in it, but it always worked before now. Is there a .NET version of cmdlg? I have heard of OpenDialog or something, but it doesn't seem to do the same thing.

Comment: If you open the form in question, look at the toolbox. Under the `dialogs` section you'll see all of the .NET implementations of what the old `CommonDialog` had lumped into one component. Each of those can also be created in code. For instance: `Dim dlg As New FileOpenDialog()`